# Training accuracy growing way faster than validation accuracy?

Tags: neural-networks, python, keras, convolution

i've been trying to solve this classification problem using a convolutional neural network for some days but no matter what I do I can't seem to find the correct hyperparameters and configuration to make it work properly.
So far i've tried changing loss function, optimizer, learning rate, number of epochs, batch size, changing the size of the input, using dropout layers, and regularizers. (it's a dataset of pictures with resolution of 200x200). I am fairly new to machine learning so I was wondering what am I doing wrong?

I'll paste below the code for the best result i've had so far.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd

classifier = Sequential()
batch_size = 64
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
epochs = 50

classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape = (64,64,1), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 29, activation = 'softmax'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = loss, metrics = ['accuracy'])
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   validation_split = 0.2)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'asl_alphabet_train',
    target_size=(64,64),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    subset = 'training')

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'asl_alphabet_test',
    target_size = (64,64),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    class_mode = 'categorical')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'asl_alphabet_train',
    target_size = (64,64),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    subset = 'validation')

#Found 69600 images belonging to 29 classes.
#Found 35 images belonging to 29 classes.
#Found 17400 images belonging to 29 classes.

model = classifier.fit(
    training_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = training_generator.samples // batch_size,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
    shuffle = True,
    epochs = epochs)
```

these are the accuracy and loss graphs:

[image: accuracy]

[image: loss]

at this point I'm not sure if my model is experiencing overfitting or I wrote something wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

first i think the code is fine and every thing is ok whyle the training as showen in the plot is progressing normal.
I think it's just beacuse you'r data is not shuffled, because when you do the validation split it actually do not take random samples it takes blocks of data, for exemple the training data in the end of the dataset is diffrent than the begining of the dataset and the diffirence is huge, try to shuffle your data and that will propebly improve your validation.